# Scalding: Fill in Discontinuity in Rows

Tags: scala, mapreduce, functional-programming, scalding

Let's pretend I have data like this:

```
(Date, Most Active User)
(6/1/2014, "Bob")
(6/2/2014, "Joe")
(6/3/2014, "Jim")
(6/7/2014, "Jack")
```

Notice there are missing rows for date (6/4/2014), (6/5/2014), (6/6/2014). I want to fill in the default "Most Active User" value for those rows to the most recent row where that value is defined. For example, the value for those rows should be "Jim".

Comment: What's the type of (6/1/2014, "Bob")? Is it a tuple or array? And how does the row with missing data look like?

Answer (score 0):

The one way you can do it is to write a function which will recursively iterate through your records and the stream of dates, compare dates and generate another list of records with missing dates and default user.

I will use `scala.collection.immutable.Stream` and [nscala](https://github.com/nscala-time/nscala-time) for my example. Nscala is a simple wrapper for java JodaTime. To use it add `libraryDependencies += "com.github.nscala-time" %% "nscala-time" % "1.8.0"` to your `build.sbt` file. The working code is:

```
import scala.collection.immutable.Stream
import com.github.nscala_time.time.Imports._

//formatter to compare strings in your record with DateTime
val fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("M/d/yyyy")
//Stream lazy magic is here. We create infinite stream of days
def days(start: DateTime): Stream[DateTime] = start #:: days(start + 1.day)
val records = List(("6/1/2014", "Bob"), ("6/2/2014", "Joe"),
  ("6/3/2014", "Jim"), ("6/7/2014", "Jack"))

//Recursion here
def fillDefaultValues(records: List[(String, String)], 
     days: Stream[DateTime]): List[(String, String)] =
//Let be cautious and use headOption. 
  (records.headOption, days.headOption) match {
    case (Some((date, name)), Some(day)) if date == day.toString(fmt) => 
      (date, name) :: fillDefaultValues(records.tail, days.tail)
    case (Some((date, name)), Some(day)) => 
     (day.toString(fmt), "Most Active User") :: 
        fillDefaultValues(records, days.tail)
    case (None, _) => Nil
    case (Some((date, name)), None) => throw new Exception("Days are out")
  }

fillDefaultValues(records, days(new DateTime(2014, 6, 1, 0, 0)).slice(0, 100)).foreach(println)
```

And the ouput:

```
(6/1/2014,Bob)
(6/2/2014,Joe)
(6/3/2014,Jim)
(6/4/2014,Most Active User)
(6/5/2014,Most Active User)
(6/6/2014,Most Active User)
(6/7/2014,Jack)
```